# How can I create a wp plugin with this code

Tags: plugin-development

I came across a post - [from code tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-wordpress-plugin-to-follow-your-favorite-authors--wp-26232) for a plugin which requires one to create it from the cpanel file directory but I need a plugin instead in zip file. Will all the codes be in the index.php
And help for this? You can check the codes  [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-wordpress-plugin-to-follow-your-favorite-authors--wp-26232) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the plugin .zip you can upload it in the wordpress admin panel under plugins -> add new -> upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the same files as in the tutorial, but on your computer, then zip them. That's all a plugin zip is.

Comment: Well, am having issue with creating the zip file. Am new to plugin development, will all the codes be in the index.php

Comment: If that’s what the tutorial says, yes. If so just put it in a zip file, and that’s it.